# What will the weather be like in Bali and Sri Lanka in November?

Tags: planning, destinations, sri-lanka, weather-and-climate, bali

I'm thinking of a holiday to the west of Sri Lanka, near Colombo, or Bali in November. Can anyone tell me what to expect weather wise in each place?

Comment: "Better" is subjective. Do you mean hotter? Or perhaps cooler? Less humid? More sunny days? It's difficult to answer such a question until you clarify it. It's probably better to ask for a *comparison* of the weather in the two places in that particular month.

Comment: Both the places are so different that I cannot answer this question without knowing what you are going there for.

Comment: Normally I would start with Wikipedia to see what it says about the climate for a given time of year, but neither the Bali nor the Sri Lanka page has a climate section.

Comment: You can check MSN Weather for that. By the way, I wonder why question about Bali is quite rare in StackExchange.

Comment: Great thanks Rudy for the feedback, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 5):

**BALI**

In November, Bali is just barely starting to enter the rainy season. You can check it in [Bali MSN Weather](http://www.bing.com/weather/overview/search?q=bali%20weather%20november&go=&form=DTPWER)

- The temperature is around 21-27 degrees Celcius.
- Humidity is around 65%
- In the month there's an average of eight rainy days.
- The peak of the rainy season would be in December - March, so in November is actually quite OK compared to December or January

I was in Bali for one week in November 2010, and within 1 week, rain only happened 1 time during the daytime.

However if you are really worried about rain, you should go around April - August, when Bali is in the peak of the dry season.

**COLOMBO**

You can check Colombo's November weather in [Colombo's MSN Weather.](http://www.bing.com/weather/tripplan?q=colombo%20weather%20november&unit=F&mon=11&seasonType=amt&FORM=DTPWEA)

- Temperature 23-31 Celcius
- Humidity is around 79%
- In the month there's an average of six rainy days.